# Access skipped lines from a pandas import

Tags: python, pandas, pipe

When importing a file to pandas, there are several options to skip headerlines etc, and specify what line should become the column headers and so on.

Is it possible to access these skipped lines for later use? In my case, some of those skipped lines contain useful metadata which aren't part of the 'proper' table, but contain things I'd still like to use.

For example, say I have this data (it's already in dataframe format from a previous script):

```
/path/to/the/originating/file
     Position  Start  End    Peptide  Chou-Fasman  Emini  Kolaskar-Tongaonkar  Parker
0           5      1    9  MSTSTSQIA        0.991  0.887                0.990   2.867
1           6      2   10  STSTSQIAV        0.980  0.665                1.052   2.922
2           7      3   11  TSTSQIAVE        0.903  0.860                1.034   3.067
3           8      4   12  STSQIAVEY        0.923  0.934                1.062   2.278
4           9      5   13  TSQIAVEYP        0.933  1.077                1.068   1.789
...
```

I can read this in like so:

`df = pd.read_csv(sys.stdin, delim_whitespace=True, header=1, index_col=0)`

The `header=1` takes care of skipping the filepath line, but I'd still like to know what the file was. As you can see, I'm using this in a pipe, so that line allows me to 'track' the contents and the file they came from.

I'd still like to be able to access (in this case) the zero-th line though to do other things with it in the script. More generally, is there a way to access lines that pandas has skipped?

Since this is a pipe, reading the file again to get just that line isn't really an option. I could read the stream in to a `StringIO` object, get the first line, then pass the rest of it to `pandas` but that feels hacky.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with pandas (would love to be proven wrong), the only solutions I know of are to parse the skipped lines separately (for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36441335/reading-in-header-information-from-csv-file-using-pandas ) so you may be stuck with reading the stream into a `StringIO` object as you suggest.

Comment: That's my suspicion too, I just thought there might be a possibility that during parsing pandas held on to the ignored rows in a sub-object somewhere and it was perhaps buried such that I hadn't found it yet!